# value toBytes is not a member of object it.innove.play.pdf.PdfGenerator play framework 2.4

Tags: scala, pdf, playframework

I'm trying to implement this example: https://knoldus.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/play2-pdf-plugin-js-enabled-and-disabled-browser/?iframe=true&theme_preview=true to generate pdf in my application so this is my controller scala:

```
package controllers

import it.innove.play.pdf.PdfGenerator

import javax.inject.{ Inject, Named }
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.{ Environment, LogoutEvent, Silhouette }
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.CookieAuthenticator
import play.api.i18n.{ I18nSupport, MessagesApi, Messages }
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.Play.current
import models.silhouette.User
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }
import forms._
import utils._

import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.Configuration

class Application @Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi,
  val env: Environment[User, CookieAuthenticator],
  configuration: Configuration) extends Silhouette[User, CookieAuthenticator] with I18nSupport {

  def homepage: Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(PdfGenerator.toBytes(views.html.index("Your PDF is generated"), "http://localhost:9000")).as("application/pdf")
  }
}
```

my index:

```
@(message: String)
@printPdf("Welcome") {
    Image: <img src="/public/images/favicon.png"/><br/>
    Hello world! <br/>
    @message
}
```

printPdf :

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="print"
            href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>

            </div>
            <div class="content-text" >
                @content
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

my dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.0.1",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.11.10",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.10",
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % "3.0.0",
  "net.ceedubs" %% "ficus" % "1.1.2",
  "com.adrianhurt" %% "play-bootstrap3" % "0.4.4-P24",
  filters,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % Test,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "4.0.0",
  "it.innove" % "play2-pdf" % "1.4.0",
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0")
```

Comment: What is your issue? Won't it compile or is there a runtime issue?

Comment: compile issue I get this error: value toBytes is not a member of object it.innove.play.pdf.PdfGenerator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a non-static method statically. `PdfGenerator.toBytes(???)` is not a static method. Changing it to `new PdfGenerator().toBytes(???)` solves your compile problem. In your case:

```
def homepage: Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(new PdfGenerator().toBytes(views.html.index("Your PDF is generated"), "http://localhost:9000")).as("application/pdf")
}
```